# JQuery Table Inserting blank rows for each valid JSON object in data source

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

**What am I trying to do?** I created an overlay that contains a search field and an HTMLDataTable. A user will enter search parameters and the client will request the data via an AJAX call to the server. All data is returned properly via the AJAX. I then convert the AJAX into JSON and destroy/rebuild the table of results in this overlay.

**What is not working?** I perform the search, and I have verified that the string of serialized code is returned. JSON.parse is properly turning the returned string into a series of JSON objects. Here is the raw returned data with sensitive details replaced with temporary values:

```
[{"id":5555,"nameLastFirst":"Shmoe, Joe","role":"owner"},
{"id":33333,"nameLastFirst":"Doe, Jane","role":"stakeholders"}]
```

That is of course turned into two objects which should be correctly populated two rows in the results table that I have coded. However, I receive the following error:

> DataTables warning (table id="myTable"): Requested unknown parameter '0' from data source for row 0.

After the error, I can close the browser alert and the result is a set of blank rows in the HTML
DataTable equal to the number of objects in my JSON array.

Now, I want to note that I googled that error and received tons of unique causes for that error. I followed EVERYTHING that I could possibly find in the search results, and none of the fixes worked, and many did not even apply to my situation. This is why I've come here.

Here is my jquery code (userSearchResults is the AJAX string):

```
$.fn.renderTable = function () {
    var parsedUsers = JSON.parse(userSearchResults);
    $("#userSearchResultsTable").dataTable({
        "bDestroy": true,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bFilter": false,
         dataType: "json",
        "bProcessing": true,
        "oLanguage": {"sEmptyTable": "There were no results given. Please try again with different search parameters."}, 
        "aaData": parsedUsers,
        "aocolumns": [
        {
            "mdataProp": "id",
            "sTitle": "ID",
            "sType" : "numeric",
        },
        {
            "mdataProp": "nameLastFirst",
            "sTitle": "Name",
            "sType": "string",
        },
        {
            "mdataProp": "role",
            "sTitle": "User Role",
        }
        ]
    });
};
```

Finally, here is the table on page load. I have it as a placeholder, to be destroyed and rebuilt when a user searches for results:

```
      <table id="userSearchResultsTable" style="width: 100%;">
      <thead><tr role="row">
              <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending"             
                  aria-label="ID: Activate to sort column descending.">ID</th>
              <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-
                  sort="ascending" aria-label="Name: Activate to sort column descending.">Name</th>
              <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" 
                  aria-label="User Role:  Activate to sort column descending.">User Role</th>
      </tr></thead>
<tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all"></tbody>
</table>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've tried everything I could find for the cause of this problem, and I worry this has something to do with the row inserted that gives the datatable column headers. I am not aware of any alternatives, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue turned out to be that the data table was created on page load with a certain set of columns; say "A, B, C, and D" columns.

However, when the AJAX returned the data, and the data was passed into the $.databtable build function, I would destroy the existing table and rebuild it. However, it still demanded identical columns. I intended the columns to be identical, but made a mistake somewhere.

Ultimately, it was rebuilding the table with something like "A, B, C, E" where "E" should have been "D".

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it for some tests

```
$.fn.renderTable = function () {
    var parsedUsers = JSON.parse(userSearchResults);
    $("#userSearchResultsTable").dataTable({
        "bDestroy": true,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "oLanguage": {"sEmptyTable": "There were no results given. Please try again with different search parameters."}, 
        "aaData": parsedUsers,
        "aocolumns": [
        {
            "mdata": "id",
        },
        {
            "mdata": "nameLastFirst",
        },
        {
            "mdata": "role",
        }]
    });
};
```

I have worked with datatables and think that we can resolve it today.

Comment: Where are you calling the $.fn.renderTable function ?

Comment: The $.fn.renderTable is appearing here:  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#searchButton").click(function () {
            $.fn.loadUsers();
            $.fn.renderTable();
        });
    });

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I just inserted your modified code, but unfortunately I receive the same error, with the same wording and numbers. Also, the rows are blank, but there is a row for each JSON object (as before).

Comment: Im going to home now, and after I ll debug it for you. I have a project with datatables at home. I did caught very much with that in the past. hugs

Comment: Yessir. I saved the changes, built my code, and refreshed the page, before searching for results again. I also verified the javascript library was updated via google chrome's dev tools (source) option.